# Disable displaying of "output window" at each compilation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build, compilation

In VS2010, I noticed that the "output window" is shown every time we compile the solution, even if we have had close it.

In VS2008, that wasn't the case. I don't mind this output window. I prefer looking at the "Error window" only, and only if it is necessary. In VS2008, it was perfect.

How to disable the systematic displaying of the "output window" in VS2010?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Go to Tools, Options, Projects And Solutions, and uncheck Show Output Window when Build Starts.

Comment: Still applies to VS2013.

Comment: In VS2015, this will also prevent the Output window from automatically showing up when running unit tests.

Comment: "... when running unit tests." It does not, in my case. I suspect it is caused by the use of NUnit 3 Test Adapter. Haven't found a cure yet, so have to keep Output and Test Explorer in separate panes for convenience. Anyone?

Comment: Still applies to VS2017

Comment: Still applies to VS2019.

Comment: Still applies to VS2022

Answer (score 6):

*While the question is related to compiling. I came to this question and I am sure other will, just to disable the output window entirely.*

*So in addition to the accepted answer I offer the following.*

In VS2013 (versions maybe more or less).

```
Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window
```

There are a number of options turned on for directing messages to the output window.

I has simply saved a unit test class when it popped up in front of me.

Comment: This answer applies more to me than the popular answer.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2013 also:
 
Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Perforce - Logging -> uncheck "Show p4 command output for file operations"

Comment: In VS2015 I do not have this option. Do you know how to disable auto Output window pop-up when auto check-outed from TFS ?
I keep getting these boring messages: 

_File.xyz has been automatically checked out for editing._